# Getting attribute from template in controller

Tags: ember.js

I have following template code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" {{bindAttr data-id="voucher.id"}} {{ action 'deleteVoucher' target="controller"}}>Delete</a>
```

And my controller code is

```
App.CreditIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    deleteVoucher: function(event){
        //var g = this.get('data-id');
        //var g = $(event.target).attr('deleteVoucher');
        var g = $(this.target);//.attr('data-id');
        console.log(g);
    }    
});
```

I new to get the value of "data-id" from my template in my controller. I have tried the codes inside my deleteVoucher function. But none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ember you don't have to do it this way, instead **you can easily pass an object to your action helper, which is available to your action handler as an argument:**

```
<a href="#" {{ action deleteVoucher voucher target="controller"}}>Delete</a>


App.CreditIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    deleteVoucher: function(voucher){
        var id = voucher.get("id")
        console.log(id);
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier than you think:

```
<a href="#" {{action 'deleteVoucher' voucher}}>Delete</a>
```

Controller:

```
App.CreditIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  deleteVoucher: function(voucher){
    console.log(voucher.get("id"));
  }    
});
```

1. You don't need to target the controller specifically, as it's the default target for `{{action}}`s
2. Don't store the data (`voucher.id`) in the DOM. It's a bad practice. Think about the DOM as a reflection of what you have *elsewhere* in your application.
3. It doesn't matter what you put into the `href` attribute when you're using an action on that element: it'll automatically prevent the link to be visited when clicked.